# Short story about a giant ship that thoughtlessly destroys planets as it travels, is visited by a victim

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, generation-ship

I think I came across this ten or fifteen years ago, I cannot remember much clearly so some of these details may be mistaken. The story is told from the perspective of a crew member, on the bridge I think.

The ship is described as utterly enormous, sleek, and silver colored; I think it has been cruising at (near?) lightspeed for so long the crew have forgotten why. As it travels, it automatically targets planets, destroying them instantly as it passes. A major point of the story is that the inhabitant of one such planet manifests on the ship and speaks to the crew, I cannot recall the mechanics of this—spiritual, interdimensional, an AI? I only skimmed the beginning of this when I encountered it, and it's been lurking in my head for ages to finish it.

Comment: I've read this, or something similar in an anthology, it was quite surreal half to do with relativistic effects on the ships crew. Let me think . . .

Comment: This sounds a little like Diane Carey's ST:TNG novel 'Ghost Ship'...? (https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ghost_Ship)

Comment: I think I read that story and that it's in the Berserker books by Fred Saberhagan.  I wish I had time to look it up, but I don't.  I think the survivor has some way of messing with the Berserker's programming by tricking it or something.  (Kind of like how Kirk messes up computers!)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_(novel_series)

Comment: @Tango: No, the description doesn't match a Berserker story. Berserker ships have an AI and are definitely not piloted by lifeforms. They may have prisoners, and in at least one case an obedient slave, but no crew. There is one case where a Berserker AI forgot its purpose (or more exactly, the meaning of its purpose), but not because of age but due to an unfinished repair. Also, Berserkers target lifeforms, not whole planets.

Comment: I'm thinkng of Stephen Baxter's [Xeelee Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeelee_Sequence), particularly _Flux_ (if the "ship" is allowed to be a neutron star).